# How do I get an existing Windows 8 installation to recognize a ps/2 keyboard?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, ps2

How do I get an existing Windows 8 installation to recognize a PS/2 keyboard?  The keyboard works when I'm in the bios, but once Windows starts, the keyboard stops working.

The NumLock light is on, so I know the keyboard is plugged in.  I checked with device manager, and I can't find any entry for the PS/2 keyboard.  The detect hardware tool can't detect it, and when I try and choose the device manually to install, the are no keyboards listed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/bug-windows-8-ps2-keyboard-not-detected-after/902dc219-6f43-479a-b129-94d4e3985947

> Windows supports both USB and PS/2 keyboards, and can in fact support
>   having more than one such input device plugged in at a time. However,
>   when a PS/2 keyboard is uninstalled and a USB keyboard is made the
>   main input device (via the Keyboard section in the Control Panel),
>   PS/2 keyboard support is disabled.
>
> Note: A PS/2 keyboard will still allow access to the BIOS and will
>   work in the boot-loader; it just won't work correctly in Windows. (It
>   will, however, usually work in the Recovery Console.)
>
> PS/2 keyboard devices are governed by a kernel-level service called
>   i8042prt, short for the technical name for the PS/2 keyboard port.
>   When a USB keyboard is added as a replacement for a PS/2 keyboard, the
>   i8042prt service is forcibly disabled. This is to prevent a conflict
>   between PS/2 and USB devices, but if a PS/2 keyboard is reinstalled,
>   the service is not automatically restarted.
>
> To switch back to using a PS/2 keyboard, the user needs to edit the
>   Registry to restart thei8042prt service.
>
> To do this you need to edit the registry, In
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt,, edit
>   the Startvalue and set it to a hex or decimal value of 1. Reboot and
>   change to a PS/2 keyboard via the Keyboards section in Control Panel.

Comment: I haven’t heard of Windows disabling PS2. Do you have any references on this? There won’t be any conflicts, ever, no matter how many keyboards you decide to connect at the same time.

Comment: Google it and you will find a lot of people having this issue and most of them follow the above steps and it works. I havent tried this but maybe check up on this as well <http://batcmd.com/windows/8/services/i8042prt/ >

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had to actually reboot twice for some reason, but it eventually worked.  Should I expect to have to re-do this process every time I plug in a USB keyboard?

Comment: Plagiarized content without attribution: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-hardware/bug-windows-8-ps2-keyboard-not-detected-after/902dc219-6f43-479a-b129-94d4e3985947